# Why is my excel calculation bringing back a "value" other than zero?

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with 3 Rows and 4 Columns of data, formatted as currency, w/2 decimal spaces. The 4th columns contains the following formula **IFERROR(C2-(A2+B2),"")**.  I want to apply conditional formatting so that if the value in D <> 0 turn red. This works for all rows but the last one.  I copied the data in column D and "paste special values" in the adjacent cell, and D4 cell comes back with 5.96046E-08 instead of zero, like the others.  Any help in understanding why this is happening is greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: Additional Information - I removed the IFERROR part of the formula, so it now reads =C2-(A2+B2) and it works as expected, but I have a very large spreadsheet that in some cases will have blank cells causing the formula to return #VALUE!, which is the reason for the IFERROR portion of the formula.  Again, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Binary arithmetic is not exact, due to the impossibility of representing certain decimal values as binary using the IEEE 754 standard. You can either round to the necessary precision, or test for a maximum difference. See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the formula in column D so that it rounds the result to an appropriate number of decimal places. For example, if you are working with currency and 2 decimal places, you could use the ROUND function:

```
=IFERROR(ROUND(C2-(A2+B2), 2), "")
```

This will round the result of the calculation to 2 decimal places, which should avoid the problem of small inaccuracies.